# Display Hierarchy in Self Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm building an employee directory application and am using self joins so all employee relationships are in one table.

I have subordinates (direct_reports) displaying and I can show an individual's manager.

Here is my model:

```
has_many :direct_reports, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "manager_id"
belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "Person"
```

Here is my view:

```
<tr><td>Manager:</td><td><strong><%= link_to "Manager", @person.manager %></strong></td></tr>

    <tr><td>Direct Reports:</td><td><strong><% @person.direct_reports.each do |person| %>
                    <%= link_to person.lname + ", " + person.fname, person %><br>
                    <% end %></strong></td></tr>
```

However, I haven't found any way to show the complete reporting hierarchy of the people above in the organization. Yes, I'm showing the manager, but I need to show their manager and their manager, etc. all the way up to the CEO.

I'm assuming that everyone only has one manager (on up the chain).

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any *easy* way to do this using a single SQL query (*as noted in comments Postgres has support for this*), unless you can limit it to a predetermined number of levels.  Otherwise, you can simply make a loop to call the manager's manager until you get a nil result.

```
<% manager = @person.manager
while manager do %>
  <tr><td>Manager:</td><td><strong><%= link_to manager.lname + ", " + manager.fname, manager %></strong></td></tr>
<% manager = manager.manager
end %>
```

Comment: Incorrect, PostgreSQL has understood [recursive queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) for quite some time.

Comment: @muistooshort: very nice - do you know if there is any 3rd party plugin that makes use of this for ActiveRecord?  The aforementioned 'ancestry' gem does not appear to.  Seems like a project just waiting to be built - I'll see if I can do something here...

Comment: Found [this article](http://blog.hashrocket.com/posts/recursive-sql-in-activerecord) doing exactly what you suggested.  A wonder it hasn't been integrated yet in anything that I can find...

Comment: I suspect that there are two things afoot: (1) misguided notions of portability ("MySQL and SQLite don't understand WITH RECURSIVE so everyone has to do it the hard way!") and (2) the general disdain that Rails seems to have for SQL and databases in general ("No CHECK constraints, no FKs, no triggers, no logic in the database!"). I blame MySQL for both but that's probably just my bias :) Using WITH RECURSIVE can easily double your performance over doing it by hand. I tend to drop straight to SQL for anything non-trivial and I don't care about database portability (which is an illusion anyway).

Comment: I got it working with this example, but after reading about the Ancestry gem I'll probably move to it shortly.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a tree-like structure, where each employee can have a manager and managers can also have boss, etc.

Try out [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry). Works great for that. You automatically get scopes like `siblings` to give you all employees sharing the same manager, etc.